# Is it possible to translate string dynamically using flutter_localization?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to localize my application.

What I want to do is to translate ThemeMode name dynamically.

> ThemeMode name returns 'system', 'light', 'dark'.
>
> For example, they should be translated to 'システムに従う', 'ライトモード', 'ダークモード'
> in Japanese .

So I would like to do like `AppLocale.${e.name}.getString(context)`.

But seems it is not supported with the library.

Is there any way to achive this?

My sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:myapp/localization.dart';
import 'package:myapp/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'common.dart';

class ThemeModeList extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const ThemeModeList({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ThemeModeList> createState() => _ThemeModeList();
}

class _ThemeModeList extends ConsumerState<ThemeModeList> {
  late ThemeMode themeMode;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    themeMode = ref.watch(themeModeProvider);
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: ThemeMode.values
            .map((e) =>
            ElevatedButton(
                child: Text(AppLocale.${e.name}.getString(context) ), <-- I would like to do like this
                onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    final themeModeNotifier =
                    ref.read(themeModeProvider.notifier);
                    themeModeNotifier.update(e);
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  });
                }))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create a extension function on enum.

Comment: Thanks for your commnet.Do you mean I make an extension and use switch statement in it?
Or is there any way to be able to translate themeMode.name dynamically in the extention?

Comment: Yes. As I commented in the answer below, using switch will make sure if flutter frameworks add new theme, your code will have compile time error and you would add translation for that theme mode as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access AppLocale with dynamic `String`. Instead, you can tweak your arb files.

> `app_en.arb`

```
{
"themeMode":"{choice, select, system{system theme} dark {dark theme} light {light theme} other{unknown}}"
...
}
```

`app_ja.arb`

```
{
    "themeMode":"{choice, select, system{Japanese expression} dark {dark Japanese} light {light Japanese} other {unknown}}"
...
    }
```

Then you can pass your dynamic String like :

```
child: ListView(
        children: ThemeMode.values
            .map((e) => ListTile(
                  title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.themeMode(e.name)),
                ))
            .toList(),
      )
```

For more about arb file syntax you can refer to [here](https://localizely.com/flutter-arb/).

[image]

Comment: While the answer works for now, in case they add some theme mode in future and developer forgets to add it to translation, there will be runtime error.

Comment: there are only 3 theme modes otherwise `other` in arb file handles that exception

Comment: right. it will definitely handle runtime exception but not the logical error. Like if flutter team decides to add a new thememode like "Amoled Dark", the dev would want to show it's translation and not 'unknown' to user. Right? So if he/she combines your solution with enum extension with switch statement without default, he/she will have compile time error to fix it.

Comment: Yup. While the idea that Flutter will have more Thememodes in the future is highly unlikely I get your point. Mixing dynamic arbs with enum extensions could prevent undefined theme names during development

Comment: Thank you, I understand @Rahul 's point, but Soliev 's answer also makes sense, as there will not be any new ThemeMode added in the future with a high probability. Therefore, let Soliev's answer be the Answer.